# Error on getting records by id using r2dbc

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

In sandbox project trying reactive webflux with springboot and postgres. I added r2dbc, created endpoints - get all records and post endpoints work, but appeared problem with requests which use path variable (get one record, or delete by id)
Here is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableR2dbcAuditing
public class Springboot2Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Springboot2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ToDoController {
    private final ToDoRepository repository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/to-do/{toDoId}", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE})
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<ToDo>> getToDo(@Valid @PathVariable Long toDoId) {
        return repository.findById(toDoId)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }
}
```

repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ToDoRepository extends R2dbcRepository<ToDo,Long> {
}
```

entity:

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "to_do")
public class ToDo {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String description;
    @CreatedDate
    private Timestamp created;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Timestamp modified;
    private boolean completed;
}
```

r2dbc config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages = "com.springboot2.repository")
public class R2DBCConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return ConnectionFactories.get(
                ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
                        .option(DRIVER, "postgresql")
                        .option(HOST, "localhost")
                        .option(PORT, 5432)
                        .option(USER, "admin")
                        .option(PASSWORD, "admin")
                        .option(DATABASE, "springdb")
                        .build());
    }

    @Bean
    ReactiveTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new R2dbcTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

And my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--        DB,ORM, and plugins-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--        Reactive libs-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

table creation sql:

```
CREATE TABLE to_do
(
    ID          SERIAL primary key ,
    version     bigint,
    description char(255),
    created     timestamp,
    modified    timestamp,
    completed   boolean
);
```

So when I execute `GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/to-do/3` I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class com.springboot2.domain.ToDo
```

I tried to define this using @Query in repository, but got same result. I suppose problem can be either in my table, or in entity, but I can't see it. And also seems `@Version` does not work(every time writes null to table)

Comment: From what package @Id annotation in your domain is?

Comment: also I can see you have id column in database in upper case.

Comment: @kerbermeister Id is imported from javax.persistence. and you are right - I change import package to org.springframework.data.annotation.Id and it works! can you write it in answer I will apply it?

Comment: I think it does not recognize id filed since it expects "id", not "ID"

Comment: @kerbermeister problem is in wrong import. org.springframework.data.annotation.Id did the job. id in database is written in lower case(maybe Intelij transformed it during execution)

Comment: @kerbermeister could you add this information in answer and I will approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be in wrong import of `@Id` annotation in your domain.

It should be from package

```
org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
```

But in your case it is from package

```
javax.persistence
```

Also, consider the naming of fields. As in your domain id is declared as "id", I can see in your create script id as "ID" (in uppercase).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Entity in rd2bc without @id. Or use it in the correct’s package name.